# Missunderstanding in my regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

Good day, i have a problem with my pattern `[\\d{1,4}]{1,3}+[x?]{0,2}+[\\'?\\d{1,4}]`

This pattern must check if the measuring system entered correctly.

The largest string may be `9999x9999x9999'9999`, and never be with `x` at the end, but also can be only `'9999` because that means radius!

So my problem is that it's correct while I'm having `9999x` or `9999x9999x9999x9999x99999` and false when `1` :/

I can't get why `1` is false and how to limit the `x` and integer after each `x`!

For more understandness this is `widthXheightXdepth'radius`.

Comment: even after highlighting your code and adding line breaks, it's still very hard to understand what you're asking.  could you proof-read your post?

Comment: First, `+` means "the preceding group one or more times", not adding parts of the pattern together. It looks like that's how you are intending it.

Comment: 1 is wrong because you have `[\\d{1,4]]{1,3}` at the beginning (which for example is 1), but also `[\\'?\\d{1,4}]` at the end, so you need at least 2 digits or a `'` after 1.

Comment: I totally believe in using regex -- in the right situations -- but this does not seem to be the right situation. Sometimes they simply get to the point where it is going to be hard to understand and maintain. I would first `String.split` on 'x' and then validate the count and content of each of the split elements.

Comment: And square braces like `[A-Za-z_-/]` define a character range.

Comment: The regex you posted could be simplified to `\\d{1,12}x*[\\'\\d{1,4}]`, where the later part probably should be (\\'|\\d{1,4})

Comment: Square braces define possible characters. F.e. [atf] maches a, t or f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). You probably want to use `()` instead.

Judging by your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618207/specific-pattern-match) you want to accept form

```
Int
Int x Int
Int x Int x Int
```

and also

```
Int ' Int
Int x Int ' Int
Int x Int x Int ' Int
```

So your pattern must definitely accept one `Int` and optionally up to two `x Int` and then optionally `' Int`.

You can achieve it like this.

```
Int( x Int){0,2}(' Int){0,1}
```

or instead of `{0,1}` use `?` mark

---

Now you said that `Int` is in range 1-9999. 
So your number will contain at leas one digit at start in range `1-9` and ten up to three digits in range `0-9`. You can write it as

```
[1-9][0-9]{0,3}
```

or instead `[0-9]` use `\\d` (it is the same - d is short from digit)

---

Now try to combine this and you will get your final pattern.

Comment: He probably wants to accept width, height and deepth as 0, making the pattern quite easy as `\\d{1,4}(x\\d{1,4}){1,2}('\\d{1,4})?`

Comment: @simpleBob from OP [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618207/specific-pattern-match) `Int - [1-9999]` so I assumed that 0 is wrong option.

Comment: @simpleBob, more likely `\\d{1,4}(x\\d{1,4}){0,2}('\\d{1,4})?`, but it's not accepting `1` and accapeting `1x1x` ;(

Comment: oh and it's also shows me error in range from `1-1111` and correct `11111` :( and `12x12x12x12` also correct :(

Comment: @xoxn--1'w3k4n How do you test it? My regex works fine for me `1`->OK, `1x1x`->NO.

Comment: @xoxn--1'w3k4n Try to use `m.matches()` instead of `m.find()`. Find will return `true` if string *contains* part that will match regex. So it will return true for every string that contains any number since your regex accept `Int` form. It will also accept `11111` since it contains `1111`1 that is accepted by regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/(?:\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}x\d{1,4})?'\d{1,4}/`

You could group together the first pattern into `(?:(?:\d{1,4}x){2}\d{1,4})?` as well, but I think the first one is a bit more readable.

You are using character classes (the bracketed part, `[]`) unnecessarily.

Also, assuming that the (x,y,z) triplet must be completely defined or completely absent, your `x?` is not doing what you want, since if you have the digits, you must have the `x` also.